# how to choose initial centroids for k-means clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means, centroid

I am working on implementing k-means clustering in Python. What is the good way to choose initial centroids for a data set? For instance: I have following data set:

```
A,1,1
B,2,1
C,4,4
D,4,5
```

I need to create two different clusters. How do i start with the centroids?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to learn about [K-means++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B) method, because it's one of the most popular, easy and giving consistent results way of choosing initial centroids. Here you have [paper](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/778/1/2006-13.pdf) on it. It works as follows:

- Choose one center uniformly at random from among the data points.
- For each data point `x`, compute `D(x)`, the distance between `x` and the nearest center that has already been chosen.
- Choose one new data point at random as a new center, using a weighted probability distribution where a point `x` is chosen with probability proportional to `D(x)^2` (You can use [scipy.stats.rv_discrete](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html) for that).
- Repeat Steps 2 and 3 until `k` centers have been chosen.
- Now that the initial centers have been chosen, proceed using standard k-means clustering.

Comment: Choose centers uniformly at random from among the data points. I didnt get this part. how do i choose it on my data set?

Comment: If you choose a random element, you sample it according to some distribution. Uniformly means simply that you sample it from a set where drawing each element is equally probable. So in your case You can do something like `random.sample(set('ABCD'), 1)`.

Answer (score 3):

The standard initialization is to simply

- choose k random instances.

there are many more methods (such as k-means++) but they often don't consistently yield that much better results than this baseline. Methods such as k-means++ *sometimes* work well, but also very often don't yield any improvement; but take a lot of extra time to compute.

Answer (score 1):

If a dataset is small as it is in your case K- means itself chooses random distinct clusters and then calculates centroids repeatedly to optimize the distance between centroid and points.

However, if  a dataset is large then instead of initial randomization of clusters there is a simple approach called **sharding** which can be done as it reduces the no of iterations required to optimize clustering and thereby saving time.

you can apply sharding as it is explained in detail here

[Sharding in k means](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/03/naive-sharding-centroid-initialization-method.html)

Answer (score 0):

One standard initialization is to assign each data point to cluster at random, and then just calculate the means of those random clusters.

Another is to just pick `k` random data points, where `k` is the number of clusters, and those are your means. This is sometimes called the *Forgy* method.

Comment: Random cluster assignments is actually one of the *worst* methods. Because on average, all centers will be the same.